# Indicate the type of reply in the Stack Exchange Android app feed

Tags: feature-request, android-app, android-app-feed

In the feed you get a scrolling entry for comments and one for answers. Both are labelled as "replies". I think they should be labelled as comments and answers.

As it is it looks particularly odd when you have answers and comments to the same question, where it shows two rows of "replies".

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate, that question says it's completed and I think it refers to the inbox, not the feed.

Comment: To clarify, i see each individual entry says answer or comment correctly, but the heading for the row, next to the icon simply says replies, when there seems to be separate rows for comments and replies. I'd expect either 1) Comments and answers on the same row, labeled as replies, or 2) Comments and answers on separate rows, labeled as comments and answers next to the icon.